# Interactive Spider Chart not working on Chrome but Firefox

Tags: javascript, browser, char, web-crawler

I needed a interactive (means the data points should be draggable) spider chart in javascript and found https://codepen.io/weslito/pen/CyphF

It's working like a charm on Firefox but on Chrome its handling is really edgy. Can some more advanced js programmers maybe help? Canvas should be supported by chrome too and the `ontouch` Events are triggered, too.

Answer (score 1):

change this in the activities.radar.init method

mouseX = (e.targetTouches)? e.targetTouches[0].layerX - canvas.offsetLeft : **e.clientX** - canvas.offsetLeft ;
                mouseY = (e.targetTouches)? e.targetTouches[0].layerY - canvas.offsetTop : **e.clientY** - canvas.offsetTop ;

Comment: thank you, that worked for chrome desktop version. Is there a chance you have a solution for the mobile version (chrome @android) aswell?

Comment: Sorry. but that I don't know!